# Placement of figure inline with text

Tags: floats, positioning, inline

[image]

I have some issues placing a figure where i want. I want the picture to be inline with my name. Any way in can place the figure in line with the text, on the left side. I have tried floating it, {wrapfigure], doesnt work.

Comment: Could you post the real code, not an image? There is a first visible error: making your image a *float* by using a `figure` environment.

Comment: … and welcome to TeX SX!

Comment: Thank you! I solved the issue but thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting the image into a `figure` environment means that it is allowed to float around; it will be placed wherever TeX thinks it fits. But you want to have it in a fixed place.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\hspace*{\fill}{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily Example Image}\hfill
\makebox[0cm][r]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}}%
\bigskip

\section*{Personal Data}
\end{document}
```

Putting the image into `\makebox[0cm][r]{...}` removes its width, so it does not influence the centering of the headline. Moreover, `r` places it flush with the right border.

To center the headline vertically with the image, you can lower the image w.r.t. to the baseline using `\raisebox`.

```
\makebox[0cm][r]{\raisebox{-4ex}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}}}%
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

In the code snippet I can see in the image you posted I would do what you are asking like this:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\par{\hspace*{2cm}\hfill{\Huge Steffen Honsen}\hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

The hspace has to be the width of the image to center your name correct in this example.

[image: results]